# Makefile error compiling for STM32F4

Tags: c, makefile, stm32f4discovery

I'm still pretty new to Makefiles so I'm having a little trouble with this. I'm trying to compile some code for an STM32F4, I got this Makefile.common for an STM32F3 and just changed the tool chains and directories to reflect the ones I'll be using for my development. Unfortunately I am getting this compile error, and while I've tried extensively googling it, nothing has been too helpful in helping me solve it.

Here's the error I'm getting

> make: execvp:
>   /home/wilfred/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin:
>   Permission denied make: *** [startup_stm32f4xx.o] Error 127

Here's the code for my Makefile.common. Thanks!

```
# name of executable

ELF=$(notdir $(CURDIR)).elf                    

# Tool path

TOOLROOT=/home/wilfred/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin                         

# Library path

LIBROOT=/home/wilfred/Computer-Science/STM32F/STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0

# Tools

CC=$(TOOLROOT)/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
LD=$(TOOLROOT)/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
AR=$(TOOLROOT)/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
AS=$(TOOLROOT)/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as
OBJCOPY=$(TOOLROOT)/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy

# Code Paths

DEVICE=$(LIBROOT)/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx
CORE=$(LIBROOT)/Libraries/CMSIS/Include
PERIPH=$(LIBROOT)/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver
SYSTEM_FILE=$(LIBROOT)/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates
STARTUP_FILE=$(LIBROOT)/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/gcc_ride7

# Search path for standard files

vpath %.c $(TEMPLATEROOT)

# Search path for perpheral library

vpath %.c $(CORE)
vpath %.c $(PERIPH)/src
vpath %.c $(DEVICE)

vpath %.c $(SYSTEM_FILE)
vpath %.s $(STARTUP_FILE)



#  Processor specific

LDSCRIPT = $(LIBROOT)/Project/Peripheral_Examples/IO_Toggle/TrueSTUDIO/IO_Toggle/stm32_flash.ld
STARTUP = startup_stm32f4xx.o system_stm32f4xx.o

# Compilation Flags

FULLASSERT = -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT 

LDFLAGS+= -T$(LDSCRIPT) -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4
CFLAGS+= -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb 
CFLAGS+= -I$(TEMPLATEROOT) -I$(DEVICE) -I$(CORE) -I$(PERIPH)/inc -I.
CFLAGS+= -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER $(FULLASSERT) 
CFLAGS+= -I$(DEVICE)/Include -I$(CORE)
CFLAGS+= -I$(LIBROOT)/Project/Peripheral_Examples/IO_Toggle

# Build executable 

$(ELF) : $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

# compile and generate dependency info

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $< > $*.d

%.o: %.s
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.bin: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d) $(ELF) startup_stm32f* $(CLEANOTHER) $(BIN)

debug: $(ELF)
    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb $(ELF)

download: $(BIN)
    st-flash write $(BIN) 0x8000000

etags:
    find $(PERIPH) -type f -iname "*.[ch]" | xargs etags --append
    find $(DEVICE) -type f -iname "*.[ch]" | xargs etags --append
    find $(CORE) -type f -iname "*.[ch]" | xargs etags --append
    find . -type f -iname "*.[ch]" | xargs etags --append

all: $(ELF)

# pull in dependencies

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

Comment: Did you check permissions on that directory and on the tools inside it?

Comment: Without more context in the error message it is impossible to say which rule is attempting to use just `$(TOOLROOT)` as a command. Could you provide more context, or narrow down the Makefile?

Comment: It very much looks like the toolchain binaries do not have the proper execute permission bits set. Can you do a simple ls -l in your $TOOLROOT directory and add that output to the original post as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change permissions with chmod (run 'man chmod' for more information).

for example,

chmod 777 myfile.c

changes myfile.c to have all permissions (rwx) for all users.